Find the value Summation $\sum _{n=1}^{10}a_n $
I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem
Q: Find the value of $\sum _{n=1}^{10}a_n $.
$$a_n= \sum _{m=n}^{10} \frac{m+2 n-1}{m^3 (m+1) (m+2)}$$
I tried to find the answer using partial fraction decomposition, but I couldn't find it. Is there any way to solve it? please.

There is a typo i think in the definition of $a_n$. Sum should go from $m=1$ to $10$ right? Also the value you are looking for would contain a double sum from $1$ to $10$ (one for each $a_n$ and then one for $n$ from $1$ to $10$), correct?

@AnCar Interesting speculation, plausibly motivated by the desire to produce an expression that will yield to some elegant analysis.  On the other hand the (current) expression of $$\cdots = \sum_{m=\color{red}{n}}^{10} \cdots$$ is a perfectly valid expression that will yield to manual computation.

To the original poster: I suggest that you first resolve whether there is a typo in the posted question, as suggested by the comment of AnCar.  Then, after you resolve that issue, and (if needed) edit the posted question, I suggest that you instead manually compute $~\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^5 b_n,~$ where the definition of $~b_n~$ is similar to that of $~a_n,~$ except that the upper end of the summation is $~5,~$ rather than $~10.~$  ...see next comment

Then, I advise you to look for a pattern in the data,re the summation of $~b_n,~$  and try to elegantly explain this pattern by the tools that you have been given, before being assigned this problem.  See also this article on MathSE protocol.

Re my last comment, if that try fails, there is nothing stopping you from manually computing the original summation of $~\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{10} a_n.~$  So, if no elegant approach suggests itself to you, you will have taken the perfectly valid approach of conquering the problem by brute force.

One way to simplify this double sum is to exchange the sums, make some simplifications and then realise that we have a telescopic sum.

We obtain
\begin{align*}
{\color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^{10}}}&{\color{blue}{\sum_{m=n}^{10}\frac{m+2n-1}{m^3(m+1)(m+2)}}}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{10}\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{m+2n-1}{m^3(m+1)(m+2)}\tag{1}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{10}\frac{1}{m^3(m+1)(m+2)}\sum_{n=1}^{m}\left((m-1)+2n\right)\tag{2}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{10}\frac{1}{m^3(m+1)(m+2)}\left((m-1)m+m(m+1)\right)\tag{3}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{10}\frac{1}{m(m+1)(m+2)}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{10}\left(\frac{1}{m(m+1)}-\frac{1}{(m+1)(m+2)}\right)\tag{4}\\
&=\sum_{m=1}^{10}\frac{1}{m(m+1)}-\sum_{m=2}^{10}\frac{1}{m(m+1)}\tag{5}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{11\cdot 12}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{65}{132}}
\end{align*}

Comment:

In (1) we exchange the sums noting
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{10}\sum_{m=n}^{10}\Box=\sum_{{\color{blue}{1\leq n\leq m\leq 10}}}\Box=\sum_{m=1}^{10}\sum_{n=1}^{m}\Box.
\end{align*}

In (2) we factor out the denominator from the inner sum which does not depend on $n$.

In (3) we note $(m-1)\sum_{n=1}^m1=m(m-1)$ and $2\sum_{n=1}^mn=m(m+1)$.

In (4) we write the expression as telescoping sum.

In (5) we shift the index of the right-hand sum by $1$.



Sorry for the confusion with the summation bounds. I think the original way you wrote this makes sense and this actually simplifies the problem.
Let $S$ be the desired value, i.e., $S=\sum_{n=1}^{10} a_n$.
$a_n=\sum_{m=n}^{10} \tfrac{1}{m^2(m+1)(m+2)}+(2n-1)\sum_{m=n}^{10} \tfrac{1}{m^3(m+1)(m+2)}=\sum_{m=n}^{10} b_m+(2n-1)\sum_{m=n}^{10} \tfrac{b_m}{m}$, where $b_m:=\tfrac{1}{m^2(m+1)(m+2)}$.
With this, we can split $S=T+U$, where $T:=\sum_{n=1}^{10}\sum_{m=n}^{10} b_m$ and $U=\sum_{n=1}^{10} (2n-1)\sum_{m=n}^{10} \tfrac{b_m}{m}$.
It is not difficult to see that $T=\sum_{m=1}^{10} mb_m=\sum_{m=1}^{10} \tfrac{1}{m(m+1)(m+2)}=\tfrac{1}{2}\Big(\sum_{m=1}^{10}\tfrac{1}{m(m+1)}-\sum_{m=2}^{11}\tfrac{1}{m(m+1)}\Big)=\tfrac{1}{2}\big(\tfrac{1}{2}-\tfrac{1}{132}\big)=\tfrac{65}{264}.$
Similarly,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
U & = (2-1)\tfrac{b_1}{1}+(2\cdot2-1+2\cdot1 -1)\tfrac{b_2}{2}+\dots+\big(\sum_{j=1}^{10} (2j-1)\big)\tfrac{b_{10}}{10} \\
& = \sum_{n=1}^{10}\big(\sum_{j=1}^n (2j-1)\big)\tfrac{b_n}{n} \\
& = \sum_{n=1}^{10}\big(2\tfrac{n(n+1)}{2}-n\big)\tfrac{b_n}{n} \\
& = \sum_{n=1}^{10} n^2\tfrac{b_n}{n} \\
& = \sum_{n=1}^{10} nb_n \\
& = T.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Therefore, $S=2T=\tfrac{65}{132}$.
More generally, if the summation in $S$ went up to $N$ instead of $10$, we would have that $S=\tfrac{1}{2}-\tfrac{1}{(N+1)(N+2)}$.
